# Is it possible to set current time as default value in a column with data type time in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was trying to create a column with data type time and trying to set the default value as the current time using HeidiSql. Below is the altered code.

```
ALTER TABLE "user"
    ADD "user" TIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME();
```

But it output an error as below.

```
syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 2:  ADD "created_time" TIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME()
```

Any idea about my mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dc37c122fb06be295ad6420a9fab82b2):

```
create table users (user_id serial);

ALTER TABLE users
    ADD create_Time TIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME;
```

You don't need parentheses around `CURRENT_TIME`.

Some other things:

- The error in your question is not generated by the SQL in the question; the column names are different.
- It is highly unusual to put the time in without the date.  Are you sure you don't want `now()`/`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?
- Don't use escapes around names.  They are just cumbersome to read and clunky to write.

Comment: Hi, Gordan. this worked for me. Actually I copied mistakenly with different column names I tried. In this case, I just need to store time only. Thank you very much :)